# Gbrowse not opening the browser

Tags: plugin-fugitive

I've been using Vim Fugitive plugin for some time now.
Recently, I tried the [Vim rhubarb](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rhubarb) plugin.

So for a github-repo it should work out of the box
but `:GBrowse doesn't open the browser at all.

Although, `:Gbrowse!` seems to work fine.

I believe it has to do with vim version.

I'm using apple compiled vim

VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Nov  9 2019 02:36:49)

Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1312

Comment: Can you be more specific on how `GBrowse` doesn't work for you? Does it give any error messages? What if you look at `:messages`, do you see anything there? Does it do any other unexpected action, or does it just do nothing?

Comment: These kinds of questions are better asked on issue trackers, imo

Comment: @filbranden When I run GBrowse it doesn't do anything like opening the code line in the browser. I ran :messages command after running GBrowse  

---
Messages maintainer: Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org> "osx_apps_install.sh" 114L, 2654C github.com/username/commands/blob/master/osx_apps_install.sh. Press ENTER or type command to continue.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Just created one https://github.com/tpope/vim-rhubarb/issues/57

Comment: @filbranden  Tried to run GBrowse on an enterprise repo.

:messages gives me this output ---

Messages maintainer: Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
Error detected while processing function nerdtree#ui_glue#invokeKeyMap[1]..78[18]..77[3]..<SNR>33_customOpenFile[1]..107[1]..123[3]..179[6]..180[17]..14:
line    3:
E325: ATTENTION

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was netrw plugin.

It's failing somehow and that's why browser doesn't open.

Maybe something to do the vim version as it works on a recent vim version.

https://github.com/tpope/vim-rhubarb/issues/57